# Smart way to extract XML tags in DB2

Tags: xml, db2

I have this issue and I know workaround solution, but it's not pretty and maybe you can offer something smarter.. ?

I have a table with one column containing XML stuff that looks like this:

```
bunch of text with tags

<AdrLine> Some address text </AdrLine> 
<AdrLine> More text with address </AdrLine> 
<AdrLine> postal codes etc </AdrLine>

bunch of text with tags
```

I need only Address from here and my solution is - find "AdrLine" and "/AdrLine" (with INSTR) count the characters in between and substract from the whole string.

Maybe there is more elegant way to solve this ? Btw, we do not have Regex available for us (FL 501).

Comment: What Db2 platform and version? Is it using XML type for storage? Have you considered XMLPARSE?

Comment: Have you tried [XMLTABLE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=table-xmltable-example-inserting-values-returned-from-xmltable)?

Comment: I'm such a noob :))
Thanks guys, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
WITH MYTAB (C) AS 
(
SELECT
'
<doc>
<bunch e="of text with tags"/>
<AdrLine> Some address text </AdrLine> 
<AdrLine> More text with address </AdrLine> 
<AdrLine> postal codes etc </AdrLine>
<bunch e="of text with tags"/>
</doc>
'
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
)
*/
SELECT X.*
FROM 
  MYTAB T
, XMLTABLE
(
  '$D/doc/AdrLine' PASSING XMLPARSE (DOCUMENT T.C) AS "D" 
  COLUMNS 
    LINE VARCHAR (100) PATH '.'
) X;
```

| LINE |
| --- |
| Some address text |
| More text with address |
| postal codes etc |

The example above is for a case, when you have a string (LOB or VARCHAR) representation of an xml document in your table.
You must use `T.C` instead of `XMLPARSE (DOCUMENT T.C)`, if your table column `C` is of XML data type.